# Entity relation

Tags: sql-server, database-design, normalization, rdbms, erd

Is the following entity relation correct? I am trying to link employee, timesheet and approver table.

There are few other tables and fields but for this question my main concern is following three tables. One employee can have more than timesheet approver.

```
Employee
--------
EmpID pk
Name
```

```
TimeSheet
------------
TSHEET_ID PK
FK_EmpID FK
Approved_By
```

```
Timesheet_Approver (one employee can have more than one approver
                    but only one will be approving the timesheet)
------------------
EmpID
Approver_EmpID
```

Employee Table Data:

```
EmpID Name
----- -----
1     john
2     david
3     mark
```

Timesheet Approver Data:

```
EmpID Approver
----- --------
1     2
1     3
2     3
```

Timesheet

```
TSID EMPID APPROVED_BY
---- ----- -----------
101  1     2
102  1     3
103  2     3
```

**OR this looks okay?**

[image]

Comment: Looks like a good start.  You may want to ponder how you will handle issues over time such as an employee departing, e.g. you (probably) still need to keep track of all the timesheets they approved, but prevent them from making additional changes.

Comment: Probably it wont be required to deleted employee data from the approver table but it can be handled if needed by adding trigger on the employee table which will be fired when the employee table column 'Is_Active' set to 'N' and it will delete the rows from the approver table.

Comment: Should i create seperate Timesheet approver table and have all the employees who can approve timesheet in it and then have one table which will have many to many relation b/w empid and aprroverid?

Comment: Do `Approvers` approve `Employees` or `Timesheets`? It looks like they approve Employees  with this design.

Comment: And you haven't provided the FKs, only the PKs.

Comment: Approver only approves timesheets, and once the employee submitted his timesheet then relevant approver will approve the timesheet and there can be more than one approver for this timesheet. If the first one is not there then the second one will do it. But somehow system needs to know who can approve certain employee’s timesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### My Suggestion

Why do you want `Approver` as a seperate table? Can you keep a `Bit` Field like `IsApprover` in Employee table? Otherwise you are creating `redundancy`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is not a complete database structure as i mentioned in my question. Timesheet and employee table has many other fields and department table is already linked with employee table but it is not shown in my question. Okay if i keep approver in the employee table then how can i define more than one approver for one employee? Employeeid is a FK in the timesheet table

Answer (score 0):

I feel something wrong in the design. This is my idea.

**Employee**

EmpID pk

Name

**TimeSheet**

TSHEET_ID PK

FK_EmpID

Approved_By

*Third table is unnecessary.*

Comment: Second table contains all the details in the third one. So its trivial.

Comment: Somehow system needs to know who can approve certain employee’s timesheet. There can be more than one approver approving one employee's timesheet and there will be number of different approvers in different departments who can approve the timesheet of different people.

Answer (score 0):

If there are several approves we can't add a column called Approved_by to the TimeSheet table.
Then we can add two more relations. One is for approvers list.

**Approvers**

ApproverID

Department

Name

**TimeSheetApproves**

TimeSheetID

Department1ApproverID

Department2ApproverID

..........................so on

Don't forgot to remove Approved_by to the TimeSheet realtion.

Comment: Aprroved_by will have employeeid who approved this timesheet. Only one person can approve timesheet at one time even if there are two approvers. Bascially we are telling system that employee XYZ's timesheet can be approved by person 'A' and person 'B' so either person 'A' or person 'B' will approve it.

Comment: " There can be more than one approver approving one employee's timesheet and there will be number of different approvers in different departments who can approve the timesheet of different people. "

Then what's this?
You told that there are more people approving the sheet. Now telling the other side

Comment: check me comments which i posted 2 hours ago for 'ypercube'. It says...Approver only approves timesheets, and once the employee submitted his timesheet then relevant approver will approve the timesheet and there can be more than one approver for this timesheet. If the first one is not there then the second one will do it. But somehow system needs to know who can approve certain employee’s timesheet.

Comment: After checking your last answer i put the comments. Department doesn't need to be link with either approver or timesheet becuase approve is an employee and employee table already linked with departments as i mentioned on my question that there are more tables and field but the main concern here is employee and approver. Please check timesheet table data on my question.

Answer (score 0):

**Employee**

EmpID - Pk

Name

**TimeSheet**

TSHEET_ID - PK

EmpID - FK

ApproverID - FK

**Approvers**

ApproverID -PK

Department

> OK this is my final answer. If it doesn't suit you can try your own one. I don't have time to read all those comments. And I was trying to help you.
>   Using the Approvers relation you can get approvers in a department and other things. Check sql queries to get those data.